How to save a file to 'Download' folder on Android with Expo?
I have a RN app created with Expo 51.0.28 and I want to save a PDF file to 'Download' folder.
Here is the code that I put down after several searches:
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
import { shareAsync } from "expo-sharing";
import { Platform } from "react-native";

export async function saveFile (data, fileName, type) {
    try {
        const fr = new FileReader();
    
        fr.onload = async () => {
          const fileUri = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}/file.${type}`;
          await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, fr.result.split(',')[1], {encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64});
          saveToFolder(fileUri, fileName, 'application/pdf');
        };
        fr.readAsDataURL(data);
      } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
      }
};

async function saveToFolder(uri, filename, mimetype) {
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      const permissions = await FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync();
  
      if (permissions.granted) {
        const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });
        await FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.createFileAsync(permissions.directoryUri, filename, mimetype)
          .then(async (uri) => {
            await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(uri, base64, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });
          })
          .catch(e => console.log(e));
      } else {
        shareAsync(uri);
      }
    } else {
      shareAsync(uri);
    }
};

It works as expected on iOS (using iPhone 16 device on simulator). However, on Android (Android Studio emulator with Android 15.0) it looks that it does not get the permissions, resulting in using the shareAsync() from the else block.
This causes several issues:

Denied permission for 'Download' folder, so a new folder has to be generated to save the files.
An error saying that 'Cannot connect to Metro...' after saving the file.

I have limited experience with React Native so I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.
UPD: The error 'Cannot connect to Metro...' only appears if I navigate to another folder than the one created for the app, while in the file saving menu.
UPD 2: It seems that the permissions are actually granted, but only for the newly created folder, i.e. for current app use. If I try to use any other folder I cannot get the permission and I also get the error specified above.

Ok, after a research I understand that '/Download' folder is platform-restricted for Android >11 so I assume there is no way/need to go around this.
